# Double free in the C++ standard library using only std::function and std::shared_pointer

Tags: c++, g++, undefined-behavior, libstdc++, compiler-bug

I recently came across a weird double-free bug in a program when capturing a `shared_ptr` in a lambda. I was able to reduce it this the following minimal example:

```cpp
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

struct foo {
    std::function<void(void)> fun;
};

foo& get() {
    auto f = std::make_shared<foo>();
    // Create a circular reference by capturing the shared pointer by value
    f->fun = [f]() {};
    return *f;

}

int main(void) {
    get().fun = nullptr;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this with GCC 12.2.0 and the address sanitizer and running it, produces a double-free in `std::function`:

```
$ g++ -fsanitize=address -g -Wall -Wextra -o main main.cpp && ./main
=================================================================
==2401674==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: attempting double-free on 0x602000000010 in thread T0:
    #0 0x7f7064ac178a in operator delete(void*, unsigned long) /usr/src/debug/gcc/libsanitizer/asan/asan_new_delete.cpp:164
    #1 0x556a00865b9d in _M_destroy /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/std_function.h:175
    #2 0x556a00865abe in _M_manager /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/std_function.h:203
    #3 0x556a008658b9 in _M_manager /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/std_function.h:282
    #4 0x556a00866623 in std::function<void ()>::operator=(decltype(nullptr)) /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/std_function.h:505
    #5 0x556a008654b5 in main /tmp/cpp/main.cpp:16
    #6 0x7f706443c28f  (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x2328f)
    #7 0x7f706443c349 in __libc_start_main (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x23349)
    #8 0x556a008651b4 in _start ../sysdeps/x86_64/start.S:115

0x602000000010 is located 0 bytes inside of 16-byte region [0x602000000010,0x602000000020)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f7064ac178a in operator delete(void*, unsigned long) /usr/src/debug/gcc/libsanitizer/asan/asan_new_delete.cpp:164
    #1 0x556a00865b9d in _M_destroy /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/std_function.h:175
    #2 0x556a00865abe in _M_manager /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/std_function.h:203
    #3 0x556a008658b9 in _M_manager /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/std_function.h:282
    #4 0x556a00866215 in std::_Function_base::~_Function_base() /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/std_function.h:244
    #5 0x556a00866579 in std::function<void ()>::~function() /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/std_function.h:334
    #6 0x556a00868337 in foo::~foo() /tmp/cpp/main.cpp:4
    #7 0x556a00868352 in void std::_Destroy<foo>(foo*) /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_construct.h:151
    #8 0x556a0086830d in void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<void> >::destroy<foo>(std::allocator<void>&, foo*) /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/alloc_traits.h:648
    #9 0x556a008680fa in std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<foo, std::allocator<void>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose() /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:613
    #10 0x556a00866005 in std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:346
    #11 0x556a008664c5 in std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_count() /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1071
    #12 0x556a00866235 in std::__shared_ptr<foo, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::~__shared_ptr() /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1524
    #13 0x556a00866251 in std::shared_ptr<foo>::~shared_ptr() /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/shared_ptr.h:175
    #14 0x556a008652ad in ~<lambda> /tmp/cpp/main.cpp:10
    #15 0x556a00865b90 in _M_destroy /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/std_function.h:175
    #16 0x556a00865abe in _M_manager /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/std_function.h:203
    #17 0x556a008658b9 in _M_manager /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/std_function.h:282
    #18 0x556a00866623 in std::function<void ()>::operator=(decltype(nullptr)) /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/std_function.h:505
    #19 0x556a008654b5 in main /tmp/cpp/main.cpp:16
    #20 0x7f706443c28f  (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x2328f)

previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f7064ac0672 in operator new(unsigned long) /usr/src/debug/gcc/libsanitizer/asan/asan_new_delete.cpp:95
    #1 0x556a00865906 in _M_create<get()::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/std_function.h:161
    #2 0x556a008657e3 in _M_init_functor<get()::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/std_function.h:215
    #3 0x556a00865719 in function<get()::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/std_function.h:449
    #4 0x556a00865578 in operator=<get()::<lambda()> > /usr/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/std_function.h:534
    #5 0x556a008653aa in get() /tmp/cpp/main.cpp:10
    #6 0x556a008654a8 in main /tmp/cpp/main.cpp:16
    #7 0x7f706443c28f  (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x2328f)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: double-free /usr/src/debug/gcc/libsanitizer/asan/asan_new_delete.cpp:164 in operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
==2401674==ABORTING
```

Once the `get` function returns, the `std::function` inside the `foo` struct owns the only `shared_ptr` that owns the enclosing `foo` object.
This means, assigning `nullptr` to it should destroy the `shared_ptr` which in turn should free the `foo` object.

What seems to be happening here is that the `delete` call in `std_function.h:175` first runs the destructor of the lambda, which destroys the `shared_ptr`, the `foo` object, and its enclosed `std::function` object before freeing memory.
However, the destruction of the `std::function` object has now already freed that memory location, leading to the double-free.

I'm now trying to figure out whether this is a bug in the standard library implementation (`libstdc++`) or whether the program is triggering undefined behavior somewhere.

An indicator that this might be a `libstdc++` bug is that with `clang++` and `libc++` 14.0.6, there is no double-free (or at least none is detected), but `clang++` with `libstdc++` does have the double-free issue as well.

Is this program breaking any rules/triggering undefined behavior according to any C++ standard?

---

I reproduced all this on an x86-64 linux machine.

Comment: Your `foo& get()` is broken, returning a reference to an object that is deleted. It should returned `std::shared_ptr<foo>`.

Comment: No, the object is still alive since there is a shared_ptr pointing to it (in the lambda capture)

Comment: There is no double free if one replaces `get().fun = nullptr` with `std::function<void(void)>{}.swap( get().fun )`, which safely deletes `foo` object. Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/a1168f65T

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I believe the relevant part of the standard is [[res.on.objects]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/res.on.objects), which states

> If an object of a standard library type is accessed, and the beginning
> of the object's lifetime does not happen before the access, or the
> access does not happen before the end of the object's lifetime, the
> behavior is undefined unless otherwise specified.

In your example, you access the `std::function` by assigning to it. During this access, the destructor of the `std::function` is called, ending the lifetime of the `std::function`. But the access has not finished, so it is not the case that the access happens before the end of the object's lifetime.

Therefore, the code has undefined behavior.

Comment: That definitely seems to be it, thanks for the reference to the standard.

That's what I get for capturing shared_ptrs in a lambda ;)

Comment: Not necessarily: *access* means something very specific in the standard; see [\[defns.access\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/defns.access), including the note: invoking an assignment operator does not in itself constitute an *access*. However, `std::function`'s assignment operator is specified to return `*this`; that's still not an *access*, but it is *indirection*, and `this` is an *invalid pointer value* when the `return` is executed, and that is undefined behavior ([\[basic.stc.general\]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.stc.general#4)). cc @PatrickZiegler

Comment: @bogdan That definition of access doesn't make sense in context. Almost all the types in the standard library are class types, not scalar types. So the paragraph about lifetimes has very little force if we interpret it using that definition. Also, consider the note which follows the lifetime rule: "This applies even to objects such as mutexes intended for thread synchronization." Since the mutex types in the standard library are not scalar types, it cannot be intended that the lifetime rule applies only to scalar types.

Comment: That definition of *access* is the only one in the standard, and it applies to the entire document; the library specification does not introduce another one. It does make perfect sense: the paragraph in the library specification refers to *access*es to scalar subobjects of a library object of class type, usually (but not necessarily) done as part of a function call. It does have quite a lot of force, too, and it does apply to mutexes just as well.

Comment: Interestingly, the current wording in \[res.on.objects\] was introduced by [LWG2224](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2224). Previously, there was only a (non-normative) note, which was replaced by this paragraph. The old note was specifically saying that any member function invocation must complete before destruction, so it seems that the intent is still to prohibit such invocations, which means that your interpretation is what LWG actually wanted to say there. They used the wrong term, which makes this an issue with the wording.

Comment: @bogdan That is indeed interesting! Will you be submitting a Defect Report? If not, I might. (One of the notes in LWG2224 says the word "access" is magic. Perhaps, but it seems to be the wrong magic.)

Comment: "magic" - yeah, exactly, were they intending for it to do its magic according to the core language definition, or were they assuming the wrong magic? :-) There was also some discussion about this on [std-discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/g/std-discussion/c/BGsVyc0Ittw/m/atiDfIqnc-YJ), but with no definite answer from someone from LWG (Ville is on the committee, but not LWG as far as I know). I think submitting an issue would be worth it. How about we discuss it [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248862/discuss-lwg2224)?